How to provide specific port numbers in VScode while connecting to GCP vertexai workbench through Remote SSH?
I have set serverport picks to specific port numbers. Yet VSCode is choosing some random ports.
Error is something like this:
Received request from hostserver port 52867 to connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 44991, but the request was denied.
Jun 10 12:48:10 instance-20240607-175601-samb1 sshd[77910]: Received request from hostserver port 52867 to connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 44991, but the request was denied.

Whereas i have defined this in settings.json:
"security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
"remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {
    "127.0.0.1": "37000-37001"
    
}

My config.json looks like this:
Host hostname
  HostName hostname
  LocalForward 8080 localhost:8080
  User jupyter
  IdentityFile C:\Users\sambita.chakraborty\.ssh\id_rsa

in ssh_config file i have added:
PermitOpen localhost:8080 127.0.0.1:37000 127.0.0.1:37001

any idea how to handle this?
My expectation is to connect remotely to workbench through VSCode.

Not related but you may want to look at: https://medium.com/@gogasca_/how-to-connect-from-vscode-to-vertex-notebooks-directly-8c078d538b0b
